# Decrypting serialized file throwing multiple exceptions

Tags: c#, encryption, serialization

I'm trying to decrypt a file from a password (where it was encrypted with the same password), but instead it's throwing exceptions and I'm not sure where to look.

This is how I'm generating a password

```
using (var rijndael = System.Security.Cryptography.Rijndael.Create())
{
    rijndael.GenerateKey();
    var key = Convert.ToBase64String(rijndael.Key);
    MessageBox.Show(key, "Key created", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Information);
    Account.CreateAccount(key);
    Console.WriteLine(Account.Save(key));
    Clipboard.SetText(key);
}
```

and how I'm saving the account (which returns true and creates an encrypted file)

```
private const int SaltSize = 8;
...
public static bool Save(string password)
    {
        try
        {
            var keyGenerator = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password, SaltSize);
            var rijndael = Rijndael.Create();
            rijndael.IV = keyGenerator.GetBytes(rijndael.BlockSize / 8);
            rijndael.Key = keyGenerator.GetBytes(rijndael.KeySize / 8);

            using (var fs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
            {
                fs.Write(keyGenerator.Salt, 0, SaltSize);
                using (var cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(fs, rijndael.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                    BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
                    formatter.Serialize(cryptoStream, map);
                }
                fs.Close();
            }
            return true;
        }
        catch(ArgumentNullException e)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

and how I load that file back (which returns -1 and throws exceptions)

```
public static int Load(String password)
    {

        Dictionary<string, Account> ret;
        var salt = new byte[SaltSize];
        var keyGenerator = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password, salt);
        var rijndael = Rijndael.Create();
        rijndael.IV = keyGenerator.GetBytes(rijndael.BlockSize / 8);
        rijndael.Key = keyGenerator.GetBytes(rijndael.KeySize / 8);
        try
        {
            using (Stream fs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            using (var cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(fs, rijndael.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Read))
            {
                fs.Read(salt, 0, SaltSize);
                if (fs.Length.Equals(0))
                {
                    return 0;
                }
                BinaryFormatter binaryFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
                ret = (Dictionary<string, Account>)binaryFormatter.Deserialize(cryptoStream);
            }
            map = ret;
            return 1;
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            return -1;
        }
    }
```

which outputs on loading

> Exception thrown: 'System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException' in mscorlib.dll
>   Exception thrown: 'System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException' in mscorlib.dll
>   Exception thrown: 'System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException' in mscorlib.dll
>   Exception thrown: 'System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException' in mscorlib.dll
>   Exception thrown: 'System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException' in mscorlib.dll
>   Exception thrown: 'System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException' in mscorlib.dll
>   -1

Comment: you better debug and look to the output of Exception object 'e'. This would clarify what exactly is the culprit block, or object in your code. Please share e.InnerException.

Comment: Just tried that, got the same output

Comment: `var keyGenerator = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password, salt);` vs. `var keyGenerator = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password, SaltSize);` Did you mean **SaltSize** or **salt**?